# how to make authentic user afte login cant going to admin page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

Not able to separate user and admin authentication.

This is My Middleware Player, The Problem is after i login as user i still can access admin Page.

**Middleware : Player**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class Player
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('admin');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role == 2) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

and this my routing

**Rout:**

```
// User Route
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/player', 'PlayerController@index')->name('player')->middleware('player');
Route::post('/player/submit', 'PlayerController@createPlayer');

// Admin Route
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin')->middleware('admin');
```

Comment: Provide more info on your User table/model. And did you register the middlware on your `app/Http/Kernel.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you registred your middleware in `App/Http/Kerner.php` right after that debug your middleware using `dd(Auth::user())` or `dump(Auth::user())` helper and check a request is entering in your middleware successfully.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    dd(Auth::user());

    // Or

    dd(Auth::user()->role);

    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role == 1) {
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role == 2) {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```